# Improving Mysql Match Against search

Tags: mysql

I've been loking into Mysql's Match Against search. The results are strange. For example, if I have a table attribute with an entry "education" and do a search (using match against) for "edu" then it finds it. But if i search for "educ" no results are returned. All the way up to "educatio" does not return results. So it only matches whole words, or if 3 letters or less match in a word.

Is there a way to improve it so that results are returned when a search term is a subset of a word in the attribute? E.g. using the example above, searching "educat" would return rows containing "Education"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want by matching `IN BOOLEAN MODE` and using the `*` operator.

For example:

```
 ... MATCH(thing) AGAINST ('+educat*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)...
```

The `+` tells the match to include only the values of `thing` that contain the match term, which in this case is all indexed values beginning with "`educat`" (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html) for how Boolean mode works in detail).

As an aside, Fulltext search in MySQL does not index words of 3 or fewer characters by default, so I suspect your match with "edu" is not working the way you think. Look at the value of your `ft_min_word_len` variable to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mark %a (a=your word or letter)that search any word that start with the same word or letter
you can use %a% that search part of the word that the start and/or in the middle of the word
and the last one you can use a% that ends with the word or letter