# MySQL - Match Against not search on single string

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

**Firstly,** I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve them but with no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Problem:** I have Execute Query but getting only First Record are get .

I want to All Record Related to search String Using **Match-Against**

**Refer Already Link**

1. [mysql-search-exact-word-from-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036956/mysql-search-exact-word-from-string)
2. [improving-mysql-match-against-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347446/improving-mysql-match-against-search)
3. [mysql-match-against-full-text-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733595/mysql-match-against-full-text-search)
4. [mysql-match-against-like-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807492/mysql-match-against-like-search)

**Query :** `select * from Student where MATCH (address) AGAINST ( '(india*) (India) (*India)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ;`

**Database Record:**

1. India
2. SPIndiaTest
3. Test2India

Comment: You probably should have started with the manual: `The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.` source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: @shadow i have already referred it and it not working in my case .. please read again my question

Comment: You may have read it, but you apparently did not fully get the meaning. You can only **append** the `*` operator. You cannot put it before the word. This is why I gave you the duplicate question as it already provides an answer to your question.

Comment: why can not add * before the word ?? I have known about *before the word and it worked but different concept .. but i want to partial word search using match and against.  that's why i put on questions.. any solutuion are there your side

Comment: i want to "SPIndiaTest" record and how to get it using match-against ?

Comment: See the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229507/discussion-between-sumit-patel-and-shadow).

Comment: Not really sure what you expect from me in a chat. The answer to the duplicate question shows you how you can achieve what you want with fulltext indexing.